# Cherrypy: Generate excel file dynamically

Tags: python, cherrypy

I am trying to have the functionality of allowing users to save table data into Excel file. I am trying to use an old trick of saving the html table code into the file and naming the file with an excel extension, which should show the table in excel.

I have the following code for showing submit button:

```
output = '<form name="export_excel" action="/excel" method="POST">'
output += '<textarea id="in" rows="1" cols="1" name="tableData" class="excelText" value="%s">' % tableData.strip().replace('<','excellt').replace('>', 'excelgt').replace('"','exceldblqt').replace('\'','excelsglqt')
output += '</textarea><input type="submit" value="Export table to Excel" title="Click here to save the table data in Excel file"></form>'
```

Here I am putting the table data into the textarea, which is set to be hidden by a stylesheet. I munged the tabular data put into the textarea so that html tags in tableData do not corrupt current page view.

The called function: excel(tableData) is like this:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def excel(self, tableData):
    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    return tableData.replace('excellt','<').replace('excelgt','>').replace('exceldblqt','"').replace('excelsglqt','\'')
```

This does the trick of setting context type which prompts user to open/save the excel file. But seems the returned values are not getting into the file. The file is always empty.

I assumed anything returned should be streamed to the user and get into the file as content. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably not the answer you are after, but creating excel files in python is easy enough so maybe the workaround is not worth it? 

Please have a look at [http://www.python-excel.org/][1], xlrd and wlwt are straightforward and easy to use.


  [1]: http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: Ah, I did a print of the value to the tableData parameter in excel() to stderr and seems it is getting empty value there so it cant stream the value. I will debug more why the caller is not passing the value here. I did a view source on the page and there shows up some data as value of the textarea.

Comment: Thanks Damian! I would definitely have used the xlwt tool for creating excel file from Python, but my table is already displayed on the page and all I needed is the simply write the table code in a file.  <br>      My issue seems stemmed from the fact that textarea value is set not by the "value" property, but by whatever is between start and end tags:  <textarea> Value </textarea>. Once I did it that way, the output is coming fine.